# Shall I upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10-upgrade

Since a Windows update on my laptop, my Windows 7 system proposes me to upgrade to Windows 10. Is it worth doing it? If yes, shall I do it now or wait a bit later?

Some details on my laptop and my usage:

- It's a Lenovo Thinkpad X230, mainly used for work: I typically use Office, Visual Studio, Gimp, Inkscape, Blender, VirtualBox...
- I use TrueCrypt. I need full disk encryption, but not necessarily with TrueCrypt.
- It does not have a touch screen.
- I intend to keep it for about five more years (unless it breaks before!).

Comment: This is really a matter of opinion and not an actual problem we can help you with. Unless there is a specific problem with your computer, this is off topic.

Comment: There is no way we can answer this question.  We can't predict how your computer is going to behave after the upgrade and we surely can't predict how long it will last, lol (such as 5 years).  I'm sorry, but maybe the question you should be asking is what people's experience has been the Windows 10 upgrade, but I don't think the final release is even available yet.

Comment: Of course, I do not expect a yes/no answer. malakrsnaslava's answer is very good and addresses all my concerns which where basically split into the four bullet points. I thought a single question would be better than four separate questions, as it could be useful to many other users of an X230.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **You intend to keep it for about five more years.**

Yes you can keep it as long as you want! Windows will not effect that and costumer support will be at least 5 years.  Windows 8 support will end January 9, 2018 and extended on January 10, 2023

- **It does not have a touch screen**

  It doesnt metter, touch screen will not effect your PC oweral all performance* it is designed to work on touchscreen devices as well as on normal screen.
- **I use TrueCrypt. I need full disk encryption, but not necessarily with TrueCrypt.**

> The development of TrueCrypt was ended in 5/2014 after Microsoft
> terminated support of Windows XP. Windows 8/7/Vista and later offer
> integrated support for encrypted disks and virtual disk images. Such
> integrated support is also available on other platforms (click here
> for more information). You should migrate any data encrypted by
> TrueCrypt to encrypted disks or virtual disk images supported on your
> platform.

So you should consider stop using TrueCrypt. I cant think of any reason why you cant use some other encription. And ofcourse that windows 10 will have some encryption support.

- **It's a Lenovo Thinkpad X230..**
  On Lenovo website, there is an offer if you buy now Thinkpad X230 that you will get Windows 10 for free. *(I know that everyone gets Windows 10 for free, but I think that company is advertising windows 10 for that device )*

So, what was your question again? **Shall I upgrade to Windows 10 from Windows 7?**

- Do as you like!